How to refresh subgrid chart?
I have a subgrid on a form in a Power Apps model-driven app which I want to refresh using JavaScript when a custom page is closed. When the subgrid is shown as a 'normal' subgrid (not a chart) on the form, it refreshes as expected. However, if select 'Show chart only', the chart is not refreshed by the JavaScript. The user has to hit the refresh button to see the new records in the chart.
This is the JavaScript I use to refresh the subgrid:
formContext.getControl("SubgridName").refresh();

[

The weird thing is, that I am 100% sure this was working at one point, because I demoed the functionality for my colleagues where the chart refreshed when the custom page was closed.
Is there any other way, to refresh a subgrid or chart? Or could this potentially be a bug?
Any help is appreciated.
